# Winpcap performance, how to receive huge amount of data?

Tags: networking, winpcap

What could be aproximately max throuput for winpcap? I want to try to sent data encapsulated in pure L2 frames via dedicated 1G or maybe 10G ethernet card and then fetch them with my app by using winpcap interface. Anybody played like this?
The source will be a kind artificial, just producing flood of bytes, technically I could add anything to the stream. Would it be faster if I simulate higher layers and fetch it by UDP stack in Windows?